# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{1}$ is not isometric to $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{\infty}$ for $n>2$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

$\mathbb{R}^{n}_{1}$ is  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with norm $\lVert (x_{1},...,x_{n}) \rVert_{1}= |x_{1}|+...+|x_{n}|$.

$\mathbb{R}^{n}_{\infty}$ is  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with norm $\lVert (x_{1},...,x_{n}) \rVert_{\infty} = \max\{|x_{1}|,...,|x_{n}|\}$.

I know the closed unit ball in the spaces have different shapes when $n>2$. However, I can't use the fact to give a proof.

Comment: Whoops, I’m wrong, misread the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that $\mathbb R^n$ with the $1$-norm is not isometric to $\mathbb R^n$ with the infinity norm for $n > 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179887/how-to-show-that-mathbb-rn-with-the-1-norm-is-not-isometric-to-mathbb-r)

Comment: Yes.Thanks a lot.